# How to render 3D object by a .obj file or URL in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, .obj

I am currently developing an iOS app with react native. Users can upload a .obj file to my app. The app will then upload the uploaded .obj file to firebase storage.

Therefore, I have 2 ways to reference the file:

1. The uploaded .obj file, and
2. The URL obtained after uploaded the .obj file

I have tried the module: [react-native-gl-model-view](https://github.com/rastapasta/react-native-gl-model-view). However, this requires the .obj file to be included in Xcode which I thinks it cannot be done programmatically with react native.

I would like to know what module does other developers use to achieve this?

Comment: There is no OpenGL on ios. Maybe you are using [tag:opengl-es] (but I'm not familiar with the module)?

Comment: Is it necessary to use something like OpenGL to achieve the task that I want? Are there any react-native module that can help me?